# Fill in missing values (nacof/nocb) in character column by group

Tags: r, string, data.table, grouping, na

Say that I have dataset like this:

```
   Object       date date_data
 1:      N       <NA>          
 2:      A       <NA>          
 3:      A       <NA>          
 4:      A 2020-01-01 something
 5:      B       <NA>          
 6:      B       <NA>          
 7:      B 2020-01-01 something
 8:      C       <NA>          
 9:      C       <NA>          
10:      C 2020-01-01 something
```

Generated by

```
example <- data.table(Object = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=3), date = as.Date(rep(c(NA,NA,"2020-01-01"),3)), date_data = rep(c("","","something")))
example <- rbind(list(Object="N", date=as.Date(NA), date_data = ""), example)
```

I know that I can fill in the missing dates for each group using nafill:

```
example[, date:= nafill(date,"nocb"), by=Object]
    Object       date date_data
 1:      N       <NA>          
 2:      A 2020-01-01          
 3:      A 2020-01-01          
 4:      A 2020-01-01 something
 5:      B 2020-01-01          
 6:      B 2020-01-01          
 7:      B 2020-01-01 something
 8:      C 2020-01-01          
 9:      C 2020-01-01          
10:      C 2020-01-01 something
```

What I would like to do is to fill in the **date_data** column in the same way as the date column. I cannot do that with the datatable's nafill option as it doesn't work with character values.

What would be a simple workaround? I have seen similar questions, but didn't find any that refer to the same problem

**Edit**

@Ronak Shah's data.table works for the original example. But if I change it to

```
example <- data.table(Object = c(rep("A",6), rep("B",3)), date = as.Date(rep(c(NA,NA,"2020-01-01"),3)), date_data = rep(c("","","something")))
example <- rbind(list(Object="N", date=as.Date(NA), date_data = ""), example)


   Object       date date_data
 1:      N       <NA>          
 2:      A       <NA>          
 3:      A       <NA>          
 4:      A 2020-01-01 something
 5:      A       <NA>          
 6:      A       <NA>          
 7:      A 2020-01-01 something
 8:      B       <NA>          
 9:      B       <NA>          
10:      B 2020-01-01 something
```

na.fill does not longer work, I get the error message: Supplied 4 items to be assigned to group 2 of size 6 in column 'date_data'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Comment: You can have a look at `tidyr::fill()`,`zoo::na.locf()`

Comment: you can try to convert to factor and then use data.table `nafill` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace empty values with `NA` and use `zoo::na.locf`.

```
library(data.table)

example[, date_data := zoo::na.locf(replace(date_data, date_data == "", NA)), Object]
example

#   Object       date date_data
# 1:      N       <NA>          
# 2:      A 2020-01-01 something
# 3:      A 2020-01-01 something
# 4:      A 2020-01-01 something
# 5:      B 2020-01-01 something
# 6:      B 2020-01-01 something
# 7:      B 2020-01-01 something
# 8:      C 2020-01-01 something
# 9:      C 2020-01-01 something
#10:      C 2020-01-01 something
```

---

and similarly using `tidyr`'s `fill` :

```
library(dplyr)

example %>%
  mutate(date_data = replace(date_data, date_data == "", NA)) %>%
  group_by(Object) %>%
  tidyr::fill(date_data, .direction = "up")
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option solved it! Do you have any idea why the following does not work: example[, date_data:=replace(date_data, date_data == "", NA)][ ,date_data := tidyr::fill(date_data, .direction="up"), by = Object]

Comment: yes, because `fill` needs first argument as dataframe, you are passing `date_data` which is a vector.

Comment: And what would be a way to use fill and still get the output as data.table? (of course, I can use what you wrote and convert to data.table but that's not neat and would slow down my code). Na.fill doesn't work for me with grouping when NA/s and character values interchange within a group

Comment: E.g. what I'm saying is that when you change the original example to: example <- data.table(Object = c(rep("A",6), rep("B",3)), date = as.Date(rep(c(NA,NA,"2020-01-01"),3)), date_data = rep(c("","","something")))
example <- rbind(list(Object="N", date=as.Date(NA), date_data = ""), example)

the data.datble solution no longer works

Comment: @Djpengo There is `fromLast` argument in `na.locf` which you can use here. `example[, date_data := zoo::na.locf(replace(date_data, date_data == "", NA), fromLast = TRUE), Object]`

Comment: `fill` is from `tidyr` so it works well `tidyverse` functions. You can add `as.data.table` in chain `tidyr::fill(date_data, .direction = "up") %>% as.data.table` to get it back as `. data.table`

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought off, but looks like a nasty workaround and I guess it's not the best thing to do within a loop over a large dataset.... What I don't understand is why fromLast = TRUE doesn't have any influence on the output in my original examle (rows above "something" are always filled, regardless of fromLast)? E.g. if it worked like up/down in dplyr::fill, in the down case it shouldn't fill the rows that are above non-NA value?

Comment: yes, actually that is confusing for me as well here but the example in help page shows the difference in their behavior. `bz <- c(2,NA,1,4,5,2)` `na.locf(bz)` and `na.locf(bz, fromLast = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `data.table` applying to all types of columns at once:

```
#change empty string to NAs if there are more columns, use set
example[date_data=="", date_data := NA_character_]

cols <- c("date", "date_data")
example[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, 
      function(x) x[nafill(replace(seq.int(.N), is.na(x), NA_integer_), "nocb")]), 
  Object, .SDcols=cols]
```